# How to change the absolute position of a constrained button

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have an image and on top of it (bottom-right) placed a button which is constrained to the right and bottom of the image. I would like to move the button 5dp to the right and bottom, so it sits a bit off, outside of the contours of the image.

Screenshot of the current layout, where the X button is placed within the contours:

[image]

XML of the button (inside a constraint layout):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/deletePic1"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/delete_picture_button_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/delete_picture_button_size"
    android:background="@drawable/delete_button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/profilePic1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/profilePic1"
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `android:translationX` and `android:translationY`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/deletePic1"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/delete_picture_button_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/delete_picture_button_size"
    android:background="@drawable/delete_button"
    android:translationX="5dp"
    android:translationY="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/profilePic1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/profilePic1"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

try add

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profilePic1"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profilePic1"
```

this is not 5dp, but it sits a bit off, outside of the contours of the image